# iptables for internet connection sharing

Tags: iptables, ip, nat

**Objective:**

I am working on an embedded Linux device with the following network configuration.

- Interface-1: 'wlan0' acts as an access point.
- Interface-2: 'eth1'  connected to Internet.
- Interface-3: 'eth2'  connected to Internet.

My objective is to NAT packets reaching 'wlan0' (and destined to IP's other than those in the subnet of wlan0) from the wireless clients connected to it to 'eth1'(or) 'eth2'. So that the wireless clients connected to 'wlan0' will have Internet access.

**Solution tried:**

I went through few links (unfortunately I missed the references) which proposed the following solution using `iptables`. I have written that as a script (ics.sh).

```
EXTIF=$1
INTIF=$2    
        echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_dynaddr

        $IPTABLES -P INPUT ACCEPT
        $IPTABLES -F INPUT
        $IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
        $IPTABLES -F OUTPUT
        $IPTABLES -P FORWARD DROP
        $IPTABLES -F FORWARD
        $IPTABLES -t nat -F

        route add -net 192.168.10.0/24 dev $INTIF

        $IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
        $IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $INTIF -o $EXTIF -j ACCEPT
        #$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -j LOG
    #Puzzled, how will the matching condition of `-o $EXTIF` be satisfied for any packets???

        echo "   Enabling SNAT (MASQUERADE) functionality on $EXTIF"
        $IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j MASQUERADE
```

I am bit new to `iptables` so have the  following clarifications

**Clarifications required:**

- As I understand a packet will be traversing the `FORWARD` chain only if it is not intended for the local host. The clarification I have is how will the matching condition of `-o $EXTIF` be satisfied for any packets. I understand that `-i $INTIF` will be satisfied as it is the entry interface for the packet.
- Let's say if I want to dynamically change the NAT (external) interface. I tried the following

  -- ./ics.sh eth1 wlan0 -> Internet connectivity is there

  -- ./ics.sh eth2 wlan0 -> I expected that there will be a intermittent Internet connection drop but eventually the packets will be NAT'd via `eth2` and Internet connection will be restored back. But this doesen't happen.

  -- ./ics.sh eth2 wlan1 -> Internet connectivity is there

Comment: Reason for downvote please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MASQUERADE` of the iptables plus the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward = 1` does the magic.

And the matching condition for the `-o $EXTIF` comes from your routes.

You should have one `route add default gw x.x.x.x $EXTIF` The x.x.x.x should be the inside IP (LAN) of your internet router.

With that default gateway the kernel knows the packet it received it's not for your network, so it needs to be routed outside within that gateway. Iptables sees that and makes the SNAT of the Masquerade.

Comment: If I correlate this right 1. `route add default gw x.x.x.x $EXTIF` says if there is a packet that doesn't match subnets of `$INTIF` and `$EXTIF` needs to be routed to default gateway via the external interface 2. So all the internet traffic will originating from `$INTIF` will have the outgoing interface as `$EXTIF`. 3. The rule that we append in the post routing chain will NAT the traffic going out of `$EXTIF` Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes but mind you have 3 eth now. Run the command route in your box. When you add a ethX it creates a default route for that network using the defined mask for that NIC. So if you're trying to contact to a computer on a subnet you have directly connected the packet should go throught that NIC. The default gw route says if I want to go elsewhere and I don't have any route which says where I need to go (which ethX to use) I should pass the packet to this gateway, and the gw will send it where it needs to. Mind you have three default subnets, but you can have more routes defined by hand ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the response. One more thing, By default my `route` command shows 3 defaults for three interfaces. The problem am facing now is in order for routing Internet packets from `INTIF` to  `EXTIF1`, I had to delete the default route corresponding to `EXTIF2`  Any thoughts on how to handle this.

Comment: The default gw should have 0.0.0.0 on the GenMask column. If you want to change the external NIC you should delete first the current default gw with "route del default gw <ip_of_the_gw>" If you want to use two internet connections connected to two differentes nics at the same you should check this link [1], it will add packet marks and prerouting to your linux networking lexicon ;-)  [1] http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87990/linux-as-router-with-multiple-internet-providers

Answer (score 0):

I think you script should look like this:

```
    EXTIF=$1
    INTIF=$2
    WLAN_NET="192.168.10.0/24"

    echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

    # Flush all rules
    IPTABLES -F

    #Allow masquerade only if requested internet address
    IPTABLES -A POSTROUTING -s $WLAN_NET ! -d WLAN_NET -o $EXTIF -j MASQUERADE

    #Allow forward from localnet to internet
    IPTABLES -A FORWARD -s $WLAN_NET ! -d $WLAN_NET -i $INTIF -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Can you please throw some light on the 2nd clarification in my question?